# How to duplicate value in one object array in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object array for customization of colors on my website. It gets generated like this when the colors are selected by the user:

```
colours = {
  "a":["red", "green", "blue"],
  "b":["pink", "yellow", "red"],
  "c":["violet", "black"],
  //and lots more
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to connect (this will vary) the value of `a` with `d` and `c` with `x`. What ever the change is done in the values of `a` should be the values of `d`. I have multiple pages like this where I have to connect different values. How can I do this is it possible? It would be nice if I could set it on the header of every page like this `a`=`d` or `colours[a]` = `colours[d]`.

Comment: Consider a js framework like Knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/  "dependency tracking" and "declarative bindings"

Comment: What do you mean by "a change is done" - do they start with different values or are they always the same?

Comment: @Bergi It starts out as an empty object `colours = {}`

Comment: @MattBall Thanks, i did not notice it.

Comment: So when do you need to connect the "a" array with the "d" array? Are thy added anytime later; do you know the connections before?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I will know which arrays to connect on each page. [http://jsfiddle.net/fYbwf/](http://jsfiddle.net/fYbwf/) here is  mini test example I am trying out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a way, I am not sure if this is the right approach for it.
On my main html page header I made another object like this:

```
 connections = {'a':'d', 'c':'x'};
 // the key to be connected : the key to connect to
```

Then in my coding page:

```
 for (ax in connections) {
 // this will create a loop through connections object
    var ay = connections[ax];
    colours[ay] = colours[ax];
 // this will make a and d, c and x equal in colours.
```

That solved the problem. Thank you all for helping and I wish this will be helpful for some one.